# Why does a minotaur have so much HP for its relatively low CR?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, hit-points

My level 4 party ran into a [minotaur](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/minotaur) and it was really tough to kill. I looked up its stats in the *Monster Manual*, and it apparently has 9d10+27 HP, which seems crazy high for a monster that's lower level than us (it's CR 3). What's up with that?

Comment: @enkryptor A user who used the site once 4 years ago returning to answer a comment? You are much more optimistic than I am :) OP, if you are out there, why do you consider it to be a high amount of hp?

Answer (score 10):

The challenge rating is based on a party of 4 well-rested adventurers. They should be able to defeat a monster of challenge rating equal to the party level. (cf. *Monster Manual*, page 9, under ["Challenge"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Challenge))

Page 274 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide* includes a table of [Monster Statistics by Challenge Rating](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#MonsterStatisticsbyChallengeRating). You can find out how HP works there. The Minotaur is challenge rating 3 so hit point would be 101-115. In the Monster Manual the recommended HP is 76.

Each individual character is vulnerable to monster attacks (a little danger is what makes the game fun), but as a party, working well together, you should be able to finish a Minotaur off fairly easily with minimal damage.

Answer (score 7):

### What is CR?

You seem to be misunderstanding what CR means. CR stands for "challenge rating". It is intended to help GMs determine which creatures are appropriate challenges for their party. From the ["Challenge"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Challenge) section of the introduction to the *Monster Manual* (pg. 9):

> A monster's challenge rating tells you how great a threat the monster is. An appropriately equipped and well-rested party of four adventurers should be able to defeat a monster that has a challenge rating equal to its level without suffering any deaths.

A monster's CR is not the same as your PC's level. A CR 3 creature is not "lower level" than a level 4 character - to the contrary it would be a very difficult challenge for a single level 4 pc!

### Were you ready?

CR is based on the premise of an "appropriately equipped and well-rested party of four". Does that sound like your party? If you don't have 4 PCs, then the GM should be taking this in to account when selecting challenges. If your party wasn't well equipped and rested (or had other tactical issues) - that is a problem for the party to sort out.

### ... but did you die?

You say the encounter was difficulty.... *but did you die?*  CR is weighed against the likelihood of killing PCs. If it was a difficult encounter and no one died, than the system seems to have worked fine. It does not purport to help GMs pick fun encounters.

In truth, picking an adequately challenging and interesting encounter is sometimes very difficult. Each party has different strengths and weaknesses that a canny GM may be considering. Sometimes they pick poorly. If you didn't enjoy it (and you don't think your strategy is the reason) give your GM that feedback.